# Plot solid lines when you have uneven values in the x axis

Tags: r, plot, line

I was trying to plot a line using `ggplot` but because the x values (days) are not even spaced I do not get a solid line. I tried instead of using `geom_line()` to use `geom_smooth()` but I get the lines with confidence intervals.

My data looks like this:

```
#df
treatment day1 day2 day4 day6 day9
1         12,7 11,1 8,7  7,4  5,9
2         13,4 11,3 8,6  6,9  5,3
3         11,3 10,5 8,9  7,6  6,2
```

Is it any other geometric expression or way to arrange the data to plot a solid continuous line?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give the code to plot?

Comment: This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want exactly but it can look something like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(treatment = 1:3,
       day1 = c(12.7, 13.4, 11.3),
       day2 = c(11.1, 11.3, 10.5),
       day4 = c(8.7, 8.6, 8.9),
       day6 = c(7.4, 6.9, 7.6),
       day9 = c(5.9, 5.3 ,6.2))

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-treatment, names_to = "days", names_prefix = "day") %>% 
  mutate(days = as.integer(days),
         treatment = as.character(treatment)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(days, value, color = treatment)) +
  geom_line()
```

If it's not the case it can be helpful if you specify the graph you hope to get (x and y variable) and the code you have run.

Comment: In the `mutate`, coerce to factor, `treatment = factor(treatment)`.

Comment: Thank you that is the type of graph I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could use `melt` from `reshape2` package and base graphics.

```
d1 <- reshape2::melt(d0, id=1, variable.name = "day") |>
  transform(day=as.numeric(gsub('day', '', day))) 

plot(value ~ day, d1, type='n', main='My Plot')
by(d1, d1$treatment, \(x) lines(value ~ day, x, col=x[1, 1] + 1))
legend('topright', legend=1:3, title='Treatment', lty=1, col=2:4, cex=.8)
```

[image]

---

*Data*

```
d0 <- read.table(header=T, text='treatment day1 day2 day4 day6 day9
1         12,7 11,1 8,7  7,4  5,9
2         13,4 11,3 8,6  6,9  5,3
3         11,3 10,5 8,9  7,6  6,2', dec=',')
```

Comment: Thanks that type of plot I was looking for